# Anyone else having trouble with API Explorer v4

Tags: api

Compare the two screenshots below.  API Explorer v3 is acting as expected, but v4 is misfiring.  Couldn't find anything related here nor in the [issues list](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.api4/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen). Can't help but think I'm missing something basic! Config is Civi 5.7.0, API v4.1.0, Drupal 7.61, PHP 7.1.22, Chrome 70.0.3538.77.

[image: APIv3]

[image: APIv4]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'misfiring' ... The layout and behaviour are different to v3 but does it work when you hit Execute? There is a display issue in the Where section - is that what you mean?

Comment: The display problem is inconsequential.  I failed to state what you surmised, that pressing "Execute" in v4 doesn't have any effect. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Sorry - are you still saying that Execute is not working in API4 or did Aidan solve the problem?

Comment: The problem remains, Execute is not working in my API4 deployment.

Comment: I'm testing this on the same set up. Works fine here. Only diff is Im using the Shoreditch theme

Comment: Thanks Tony.  I'm standing up another test instance, maybe I missed something in the installs.

Comment: @tony-horrocks - feel free to answer the question, my second test instance worked correctly.  I.e. looks like cockpit error and I can't re-produce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im replicating your API4. I'm testing this on the same set up. Works fine here. Only diff is Im using the Shoreditch theme.

Perhaps you need to do a reinstall or clear caches?

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Shoreditch is NOT a requirement for using APIv4, but IS a requirement for APIv4 Explorer.